# How to update an element from a 2d label array on click?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to set up a GUI for the Gomoku game using QT. So far, I managed to create a 2D array of cells and I attached an image with an empty cell on all of them. Right now I am trying to update a cell on mouse click, but can't figure out how to do that properly. I can't figure out how to send a signal containing the index of the cell that I want to change(cells[x][y]).

I have tried to put together some signals and slots but I wasn't able to make them work.

This is my GameCell.h :

```
class GameCell : public QLabel
{
public:
    enum State {Unused, White, Black};
    GameCell(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    State getState() const { return currentState; }
    void setState(State newState);
private:
    State currentState;
    void updateCell();
};
```

And this is GameCell.cpp :

```
#include "gamecell.h"

GameCell::GameCell(QWidget *parent) : QLabel (parent), currentState(Unused)
{
    updateCell();
}

void GameCell::setState(State newState) {
    if (currentState != newState) {
        currentState = newState;
        updateCell();
    }
}

void GameCell::updateCell(){
    QImage cellImage;
    switch (currentState) {
    case Unused:
        cellImage.load("emptyCell.png");
        break;
    case White:
        cellImage.load("whiteCell.png");
        break;
    case Black:
        cellImage.load("blackCell.png");
        break;
    }
    this->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(cellImage));
}
```

This is how I store the cells on the screen:

```
GameMap::GameMap(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    layout = new QGridLayout (this);
    for(int column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
        for(int row = 0; row < Rows; row++) {
            GameCell* cell = new GameCell(this);
            cells[column][row] = cell;
            layout->addWidget(cell, row, column);
        }
}
```

And this is how I display them, in the Game class:

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent) : QDialog (parent)
{
    board = new GameMap (this);

    layout = new QHBoxLayout (this);
    layout->addWidget(board);
    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Gomoku"));
}
```

I am hoping that you can help me with an approach I should try to implement. I am new to QT and couldn't find any help on my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A `QTableWidget` would be a better way to handle your game map and easier to use.

Comment: @Romha Korev
Thank you for your answer. How should I manage the events with a QTableWidget?

Comment: Use the signal `QTableWidget::itemClicked`.